# Kendo UI toolbar align

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In Kendo UI Grid toolbar buttons. I wondering it is possible to align *excel* and *pdf* only to the righthand side of the panel. And *Create* will maintain at left side.

```
toolbar: ["create", "excel", "pdf"],
```

I have been try `.k-grid-toolbar a { float:right; }` ,but it align all button to the right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to do it. The buttons have fixed class names you can use.

See the snippet for a demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
    <style>
        .k-grid-toolbar {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
        }
      
        .k-grid-toolbar .k-grid-excel {
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  toolbar: ["create", "excel", "pdf"],
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33},
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" }
    }
  },
  editable: true
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html())` for it. Take a look at [this demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could access a specific link in CSS by its index with `:nth-child()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child